# How to bind a key to run a command and insert its output into the bash command line?

Tags: bash, command-line, key-bindings

There are various command line utilities that allow interactively choosing a file and then print the user's selection to stdout, such as [fzf](https://github.com/junegunn/fzf) or [ranger](https://github.com/ranger/ranger/). This feature allows for example running the `cat "$(fzf)"` command to first choose a file and then display its contents. However, a downside of doing this is that the command is stored in its unexpanded form in the command history and therefore it is not possible to see what file was chosen or to run it again. Additionally, there is no way to double-check the exact command that will be run, which would be especially beneficial with multiple arguments, for example in `cp "$(fzf)" "$(fzf)"`.

To get around this issue, **I would like to bind a hotkey to open a file picker and insert the selected filename directly into the command line being edited**.

---

This is the best I could come up with (here I use `date` instead of `fzf` or `ranger` for a demonstration because it does not need to be installed so everyone can try):

```bash
bind -x '"\e\C-s":"selection=$(date)"'
bind '"\e\C-e": shell-expand-line'
bind '"\ef":" \"$selection\"\e\C-s\e\C-e"'
```

Example usage: Type `echo` then press Alt-F. The command line becomes `echo Sun Jul 30 19:55:16 CEST 2023`.

Explanation:

- The first line creates a binding for a shell command that sets a variable named `selection` to the value printed by the command `date` (or `fzf` or `ranger`).
- The second line creates a binding for a readline function that does shell expansion, replacing variables with their values. (This is a default binding by the way, I only added this for completeness.)
- The third line creates a binding for a macro that types the string  `"$selection"` into the command line then presses the hot keys for the first two bindings, thereby setting a value for the `selection` variable and replacing it with that value.

What I don't like in this solution:

- Three separate bindings are necessary, because a single binding can only contain either a shell command, a readline command or a keypress macro.
- If a shell variable named `selection` is used by the user, it gets overwritten. (This could be mitigated by picking a less frequent name. It would still pollute the variable space though, unless I add one more binding to unset it.)
- It has the undesired side effect that the shell expansion is applied to the entire command line, not just the `$selection` variable reference.
- The most severe problem though is that the inserted filename is not properly escaped, so if it contains special characters, the command line will be incorrect and potentially dangerous. (In the bindings above, I enclosed the `$selection` variable reference in quotes. I hoped that this would result in `echo "Sun Jul 30 19:55:16 CEST 2023"`, or `echo Sun\ Jul\ 30\ 19:55:16\ CEST\ 2023`, but it does not.)

Is there a better way?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think,instead of using multiple bindings and a shell variable, better to use a custom shell function, so first of all define a shell function in your shell configuration file `~/.bashrc`!

```
pick_file() {
  local file
  file=$(fzf --preview "cat {}")
  if [ -n "$file" ]; then
    file=$(printf "%q" "$file")  #for escape special characters in the filename
    READLINE_LINE="${READLINE_LINE:0:$READLINE_POINT}$file${READLINE_LINE:$READLINE_POINT}"
    READLINE_POINT=$((READLINE_POINT + ${#file}))
  fi
}
```

then bind a hotkey to the `pick_file` like this :

```
bind -x '"\C-x\C-f": pick_file'
```

reload your shell configuration like this:

```
source ~/.bashrc
```

now,easily press the assigned hotkey(`Ctrl+X` and `Ctrl+F`) to open the file picker, and after selecting a file, it will be inserted at the current cursor position in the command line!

Comment: I didn't know that one can so easily modify the command line with READLINE_* variables, very nice! Thanks for pointing me to this direction. However, your solution still has the problem with special chars in the filename. It can easily be fixed though by adding `file=$(printf "%q" "$file")` as the first command in the `if` block. You may consider updating your answer with this (or your own) fix for the escaping and then I can mark it as accepted.

Comment: @Zoltan good point, thnx!